# Finding out the licenses of JAR libraries

Tags: java, maven-2, licensing, jar, identification

I use Maven to build my web app projects, when I add some dependent library to the pom file, it again adds some more dependent jars to the project recursively. Is there a way to find out or restrict that only jars having a certain type of license - say Apache License, BSD etc should be included. Or is there a way to find out that a jar file is under GPL/ASL etc without going to the website for each jar in the application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Maven ["Project Info Reports" plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/) produces a [Dependencies report](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html) that includes the Licenses for the dependencies.  Here's [an example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/dependencies.html).

Obviously, this depends on the dependent POMs declaring their dependencies properly, and it requires that you build your site documentation "online".

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this is what I exactly wanted. Though some of the libraries are under unknown, but I can live with it :)

Answer (score 6):

During the acquisition of a company I was working for, the acquiring company used the following software / consultancy to do what you're describing.

http://www.blackducksoftware.com/transact

Although I'm guessing you were probably looking for a free alternative. There may be other methods, but the fact this company makes money doing this suggests an alternative is probably less thorough/accurate.

Comment: Yes, a free alternative will be great!

Comment: A free alternative would be "scancode-toolkit". You can find it on Github: https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit

Answer (score 3):

I also find this website (https://www.versioneye.com) provides license info. For instance, https://www.versioneye.com/java/tomcat:jasper-runtime/5.5.23 says License: Apache License 2.0

> **October 19, 2017**
>
> I’m shutting down VersionEye by end of this year!
>
> I started the project round about 6 years ago and so far it was a
> journey with many ups and downs. The typical StartUp rollercoaster
> thing. I raised Money from a big VC in Berlin and almost went bankrupt
> after that. Raised Money again from small Angel Investors to prevent
> bankruptcy. Won one of the biggest Software companies in the world as
> customer and established a stable income for the company.

Comment: unfortunately versioneye is going to shut down their service in early 2018, but their API was great

Answer (score 1):

A free alternative for a license scanner is the "scancode-toolkit". It is able to scan your codebase for copyright information, license texts etc.

But like @Stephen C mentioned in his answer, it won't be always able to detect the license for a dependency.

https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit